# Duplicate setInterval Events in React App

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, webview, setinterval

For context, I have a React app running in an android webview app on a tablet. Every 5 minutes, a "heartbeat" event is sent from the tablet to our reporting system. When the app first launches on the device, everything appears normal. Sometimes (not everytime) this events gets duplicated or even appears 3 times, each a few seconds apart.

Here's the console log from the device:

```
8/6/2020, 2:14:43 AM][ID 19940]: Heartbeat: ,{"timestamp":1596694483332,"position":{"lat":44,"lng":44},"tablet":"168d6460-cdd3-11ea-b082-25541e4e57c5","driver":"****",...}
[8/6/2020, 2:14:54 AM][ID 19941]: Heartbeat: ,{"timestamp":1596694494054,"position":{"lat":44,"lng":44},"tablet":"168d6460-cdd3-11ea-b082-25541e4e57c5","driver":"****", ... }
```

This is what the React code looks like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const intervals = [];
    const mixpanelHeartbeat = async () => {
      let analyticsInfo = await getAnalyticsInfo();
      mixpanel.track("Heartbeat", analyticsInfo);
    };

    intervals.push(setInterval(mixpanelHeartbeat, heartBeatInterval));

    socket.on("broadcast", () => ...);

    socket.on("auth", async () => ... );
    socket.on('changeTheme', () => ... );

    return () => {
      socket.off('broadcast');
      socket.off('auth');
      socket.off('changeTheme');
      intervals.forEach(interval => clearInterval(interval));
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?